# Changing attribute interupts other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

Change of an attribute src seems to interupt other functions, even those not connected to the img. They don't work properly although when the line of code changing the attribute isn't called everything works perfectly fine.

I have my scripts.js that handles navigation - whenever you click header it should fade in content, change it and fade it back onto the screen.

The html of content that is to be changed:

```
<div id="photoContainer">
    <div id="photoSection">
        <img id="showedPhoto" src="img/photo1.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
#photoContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    
    z-index: -1;
}

#photoSection
{
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

And the most important, script:

```
/*
*   1. Hides photo after 0.2s of pressing button
*   2. Changes photo to another one
*   3. Shows photo
*/
function SwipePhoto(newSectionNo)
{
    if(newSectionNo != currentSectionNo)
    {
        currentSectionNo = newSectionNo;
        
        setTimeout(HidePhoto, 200);
        setTimeout(HideContent, 200);
        
        setTimeout(function() { changeContent(newSectionNo) }, 600);
        
        setTimeout(ShowPhoto, 1000);
        setTimeout(ShowContent, 1000);
    }
}
```

HidePhoto, HideContent, ShowPhoto & ShowContent are just basic fadeIn/Out functions but the keypoint is the changeContent:

```
function changeContent(photoNo)
{
    document.getElementById("showedPhoto").src = "img/photo" + photoNo + ".png";//THIS ONE
    //showedPhoto.attr("src", "img/photo" + photoNo + ".png"); SAME SITUATION OCCUR WHILE USING JQUERY
    content.html(text[photoNo - 1]);
    sectionHeader.html(header[photoNo - 1]);
}
```

Without the line of code: `document.getElementById("showedPhoto").src = "img/photo" + photoNo + ".png";` everything works as it should - smooth & clean (except the photo always stays the same which is not good).
But when the attribute src of img is changed all functions that should slowly fadeOut content don't seem to be working. The picture shows without any fade out effect. What is interesting, not only the image is affected as other sections also stop working, they just appear (although they worked fine before adding the line).

I fell like this is a bit more complex so if anyone could help I would be soooo grateful.

If I should add anything to help you understand the code please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
If anyone experiences the same problem try to lower the resolution of photos, in my case they were too big to enable the website work flowlessly.